# Interrupted time series regression in R; creating function to conduct multiple iterations

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, regression

I am doing interrupted time series regression analysis to help see if there is a significant non-zero change in values after a particular event. Here are two mock dataframes; one which has dates and values, another with event names and the corresponding date to that event:-

```
#dataset 1
eventDate<-structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268, 
                       18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18273, 18274, 18275, 18276, 18277, 
                       18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18286, 
                       18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 18293, 18294, 18295, 
                       18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18300, 18301, 18302, 18303, 18304, 
                       18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 18311, 18312, 18313, 
                       18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 18320, 18321, 18322, 
                       18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 18329, 18330, 18331, 
                       18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 
                       18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 18346, 18347, 18348, 18349, 
                       18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 18356, 18357, 18358, 
                       18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 18365, 18366, 18367, 
                       18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 
                       18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 18381, 18382, 18383, 18384, 18385, 
                       18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 18393, 18394, 
                       18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 18401, 18402, 18403, 
                       18404, 18405, 18406, 18407, 18408, 18409, 18410, 18411, 18412, 
                       18413, 18414, 18415, 18416, 18417, 18418, 18419, 18420, 18421, 
                       18422, 18423, 18424, 18425, 18426, 18427, 18428, 18429, 18430, 
                       18431, 18432, 18433, 18434, 18435, 18436, 18437, 18438, 18439, 
                       18440, 18441, 18442, 18443, 18444, 18445, 18446, 18447, 18448, 
                       18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 18454, 18455, 18456, 18457, 
                       18458, 18459, 18460, 18461, 18462, 18463, 18464, 18465, 18466, 
                       18467, 18468, 18469, 18470, 18471, 18472, 18473, 18474, 18475, 
                       18476, 18477, 18478, 18479, 18480, 18481, 18482, 18483, 18484, 
                       18485, 18486, 18487, 18488, 18489, 18490, 18491, 18492, 18493, 
                       18494, 18495, 18496, 18497, 18498, 18499, 18500, 18501, 18502, 
                       18503, 18504, 18505, 18506, 18507, 18508, 18509, 18510, 18511, 
                       18512, 18513, 18514, 18515, 18516, 18517, 18518, 18519, 18520, 
                       18521, 18522, 18523, 18524, 18525, 18526, 18527, 18528, 18529, 
                       18530, 18531, 18532, 18533, 18534, 18535, 18536, 18537, 18538, 
                       18539, 18540, 18541, 18542, 18543, 18544, 18545, 18546, 18547, 
                       18548, 18549, 18550, 18551, 18552, 18553, 18554, 18555, 18556, 
                       18557, 18558, 18559, 18560, 18561, 18562, 18563, 18564, 18565, 
                       18566, 18567, 18568, 18569, 18570, 18571, 18572, 18573, 18574, 
                       18575, 18576, 18577, 18578, 18579, 18580, 18581, 18582, 18583, 
                       18584, 18585, 18586, 18587, 18588, 18589, 18590, 18591, 18592, 
                       18593, 18594, 18595, 18596, 18597, 18598, 18599, 18600, 18601, 
                       18602, 18603, 18604, 18605, 18606, 18607, 18608, 18609, 18610, 
                       18611, 18612, 18613, 18614, 18615, 18616, 18617, 18618, 18619, 
                       18620, 18621, 18622, 18623, 18624, 18625, 18626, 18627), class = "Date")

Count<-c(46L, 58L, 46L, 60L, 42L, 56L, 44L, 60L, 48L, 43L, 50L, 45L, 
         55L, 57L, 47L, 46L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 58L, 60L, 58L, 50L, 55L, 51L, 
         43L, 60L, 51L, 51L, 59L, 44L, 44L, 42L, 48L, 50L, 60L, 53L, 57L, 
         56L, 60L, 52L, 43L, 50L, 55L, 49L, 53L, 50L, 48L, 45L, 51L, 59L, 
         56L, 53L, 45L, 52L, 122L, 100L, 91L, 82L, 60L, 55L, 58L, 42L, 
         53L, 59L, 47L, 58L, 54L, 56L, 49L, 46L, 41L, 48L, 40L, 59L, 43L, 
         46L, 59L, 47L, 51L, 54L, 46L, 46L, 53L, 50L, 51L, 57L, 48L, 60L, 
         59L, 46L, 53L, 50L, 44L, 42L, 58L, 55L, 59L, 57L, 42L, 52L, 43L, 
         54L, 47L, 53L, 44L, 48L, 42L, 56L, 59L, 46L, 49L, 47L, 52L, 58L, 
         42L, 52L, 41L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 52L, 43L, 40L, 56L, 47L, 46L, 50L, 
         45L, 54L, 53L, 50L, 53L, 48L, 58L, 40L, 43L, 55L, 41L, 46L, 46L, 
         55L, 46L, 46L, 52L, 59L, 59L, 46L, 43L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 41L, 40L, 
         44L, 47L, 55L, 44L, 54L, 58L, 56L, 43L, 58L, 45L, 53L, 42L, 57L, 
         59L, 42L, 40L, 53L, 60L, 58L, 40L, 59L, 54L, 41L, 59L, 48L, 48L, 
         43L, 47L, 50L, 50L, 53L, 50L, 43L, 41L, 43L, 51L, 53L, 40L, 52L, 
         43L, 53L, 51L, 51L, 49L, 53L, 40L, 45L, 59L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 42L, 
         47L, 47L, 45L, 50L, 46L, 60L, 40L, 48L, 43L, 59L, 58L, 55L, 48L, 
         44L, 53L, 60L, 52L, 54L, 42L, 44L, 52L, 51L, 47L, 53L, 45L, 41L, 
         56L, 45L, 56L, 52L, 57L, 48L, 47L, 52L, 58L, 51L, 41L, 53L, 155L, 
         123L, 98L, 90L, 84L, 71L, 58L, 50L, 54L, 45L, 58L, 48L, 49L, 
         60L, 41L, 60L, 46L, 40L, 50L, 49L, 57L, 58L, 56L, 58L, 51L, 53L, 
         41L, 45L, 58L, 51L, 50L, 56L, 42L, 59L, 42L, 53L, 57L, 52L, 50L, 
         43L, 43L, 59L, 41L, 54L, 56L, 45L, 42L, 55L, 50L, 58L, 48L, 54L, 
         41L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 50L, 40L, 51L, 42L, 55L, 44L, 54L, 51L, 45L, 
         58L, 40L, 46L, 46L, 40L, 57L, 53L, 40L, 49L, 52L, 50L, 50L, 59L, 
         42L, 57L, 55L, 52L, 57L, 52L, 43L, 48L, 48L, 40L, 42L, 48L, 41L, 
         47L, 53L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 43L, 60L, 51L, 56L, 53L, 42L, 52L, 56L, 
         48L, 44L, 44L, 53L, 60L, 55L, 56L, 45L, 41L, 54L, 43L, 59L, 48L, 
         46L, 50L, 47L, 56L, 57L)


data<-data.frame(eventDate,Count)


#dataset 2
Event<-c("event_a", "event_b", "event_c", "event_d", "event_e", "event_f", 
  "event_g")

Event_Date<-structure(c(18289, 18317, 18358, 18444, 18506, 18528, 18547), class = "Date")

events_dates<-data.frame(Event, Event_Date)
```

Here are two examples of what I am doing. One example has a significant result, one example has a non-significant result.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)



#significant result
event_date<-as.Date("2020-09-01")
before_period<-as.Date(event_date)-21
after_period<-as.Date(event_date)+21

data_filtered<-data%>%
  filter(eventDate>=as.Date(before_period) & eventDate<=as.Date(after_period))

data_filtered<-data_filtered%>%
  mutate(DayNumber=row_number())
data_filtered$intv_trend <- cumsum(data_filtered$eventDate >= as.Date(event_date))
data_filtered$Post_event<-ifelse(data_filtered$eventDate<event_date,0,1)
data_filtered <- data_filtered %>%
  mutate(lag_count = lag(Count))

data_filtered

fit <- glm(Count ~ DayNumber+ Post_event + intv_trend+log(lag_count),
                       family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)


summary(fit)

data_filtered$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))
data_filtered$fit2 = c(NA, predict(fit, type="response"))

data_filtered$Group<-ifelse(data_filtered$Post_event==0, "Pre-event","Post-event")
data_filtered$Group<-factor(data_filtered$Group, levels = c("Pre-event","Post-event"))


ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x=DayNumber, y = Count, colour=Group)) + 
  geom_line()+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +ggtitle("Count before and after event")+
            geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")

ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = DayNumber, y = fit2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour="")+ggtitle("Count (Fitted); Method=lm")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")



#non-significant result
event_date<-as.Date("2020-01-28")
before_period<-as.Date(event_date)-21
after_period<-as.Date(event_date)+21

data_filtered<-data%>%
  filter(eventDate>=as.Date(before_period) & eventDate<=as.Date(after_period))

data_filtered<-data_filtered%>%
  mutate(DayNumber=row_number())
data_filtered$intv_trend <- cumsum(data_filtered$eventDate >= as.Date(event_date))
data_filtered$Post_event<-ifelse(data_filtered$eventDate<event_date,0,1)
data_filtered <- data_filtered %>%
  mutate(lag_count = lag(Count))

data_filtered

fit <- glm(Count ~ DayNumber+ Post_event + intv_trend+log(lag_count),
           family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)


summary(fit)

data_filtered$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))
data_filtered$fit2 = c(NA, predict(fit, type="response"))

data_filtered$Group<-ifelse(data_filtered$Post_event==0, "Pre-event","Post-event")
data_filtered$Group<-factor(data_filtered$Group, levels = c("Pre-event","Post-event"))

ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x=DayNumber, y = Count, colour=Group)) + 
  geom_line()+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +ggtitle("Count before and after event")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")

ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = DayNumber, y = fit2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(colour="")+ggtitle("Count (Fitted); Method=lm")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")
```

Each of the `event_date` variables are from the `event_dates` dataframe.

I have a long list of dates of which I want to run through the analysis with, so I need a function that will help me do this efficiently. I want it to return  the regression fit summary and the two plots for each of the event. Here is my attempt thus far (as you can tell, not a good one):-

```
#data1 represents data, data2 represents events_dates, n_days is number of days before and after event_date that I want to filter from data 
TS_Intervention_Func<-function(data1,data2,n_days){
  
  myresultslist<-list()
  
  
  for (i in data2$Event_Date) {
    
    event_date<-as.Date(i)
    before_period<-as.Date(event_date)-n_days
    after_period<-as.Date(event_date)+n_days
    
    
    data_filtered<-data1%>%
      filter(eventDate>=as.Date(before_period) & eventDate<=as.Date(after_period))
    
    
    data_filtered<-data_filtered%>%
      mutate(DayNumber=row_number())
    data_filtered$intv_trend <- cumsum(data_filtered$eventDate >= as.Date(event_date))
    data_filtered$Post_event<-ifelse(data_filtered$eventDate<event_date,0,1)
    data_filtered <- data_filtered %>%
      mutate(lag_count = lag(Count))
    
    
    fit <- glm(Count ~ DayNumber+ Post_event + intv_trend+log(lag_count),
               family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)
    
    
    results<-summary(fit)
    
    data_filtered$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))
    data_filtered$fit2 = c(NA, predict(fit, type="response"))
    
    data_filtered$Group<-ifelse(data_filtered$Post_event==0, "Pre-event","Post-event")
    data_filtered$Group<-factor(data_filtered$Group, levels = c("Pre-event","Post-event"))
    
    
    plot_1<-ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x=DayNumber, y = Count, colour=Group)) + 
      geom_line()+geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +ggtitle("Count before and after event",paste0(event_date))+
      geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")
    
    plot_2<-ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = DayNumber, y = fit2)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_smooth(method="lm", se=F, aes(colour=Group)) +
      theme_bw() +
      labs(colour="")+ggtitle("Count (Fitted); Method=lm", paste0(event_date))+
      geom_vline(xintercept = 22,linetype="dotted")+labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")
    
    
    myresultslist[[i]] <- do.call(results,plot1,plot_2) 
    
  }
return(myresultslist)
}



TS_Intervention_Func(data,events_dates,21)
#Error in as.Date.numeric(i) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

In short, I want the function to do three things:-

1. To take each date from the `event_dates` dataframe and run an iteration of the analysis on that date within the `data`
2. To store the `fit` summary and the two corresponding plots to that event date and save it in the list (if the event name can be saved with it to make it easier to look-up, then all the better)
3. This is desirable; if the list can be split into two sections, one where the significant results have been saved and another where the non-significant results have been saved.

A big ask, but any help is appreciated as always :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily the most efficient way to do this, but I wanted to keep it simple and understandable.

I cleaned up your code a little bit and put it in a function. First I write a function which takes care of one event date:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


reg_fun <- function(event_date, data) {


  before_period <- as.Date(event_date) - 21
  after_period <- as.Date(event_date) + 21
  
  data_filtered <- data %>%
    filter(eventDate >= as.Date(before_period) &
             eventDate <= as.Date(after_period)) %>% 
    mutate(DayNumber = row_number()) %>% 
    mutate(intv_trend = cumsum(eventDate >= event_date)) %>% 
    mutate(Post_event = as.integer(!eventDate < event_date)) %>% 
    mutate(lag_count = lag(Count))
  
  
  fit <- glm(Count ~ DayNumber+ Post_event + intv_trend+log(lag_count),
             family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)
  
  
  fit_summary <- summary(fit)
  
  
  
  data_filtered$fit <- exp(c(NA, predict(fit)))
  data_filtered$fit2 = c(NA, predict(fit, type = "response"))
  
  data_filtered$Group <-
    ifelse(data_filtered$Post_event == 0, "Pre-event", "Post-event")
  data_filtered$Group <-
    factor(data_filtered$Group, levels = c("Pre-event", "Post-event"))
  
  
  plot1 <- ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = DayNumber, y = Count, colour = Group)) +
    geom_line() + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, aes(colour = Group)) +
    ggtitle("Count before and after event") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 22, linetype = "dotted") + labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")
  
  plot2 <- ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = DayNumber, y = fit2)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, aes(colour = Group)) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(colour = "") + ggtitle("Count (Fitted); Method=lm") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 22, linetype = "dotted") + labs(caption = "Dotted line represents time of event")
  
  output <- list(
    event_date = event_date,
    fit = fit,
    summary = fit_summary,
    plot1 = plot1,
    plot2 = plot2,
    signif = sum(coef(fit_summary)[, 4] < 0.05) > 1 # see if any is significant (p-value for intercept is always < 0.05 so we want more than one significant value)
  )
  
  return(output)
}
```

Now we can test this with one date. As you can see above, the output is a list, which I think is most appropriate in this case.

```
test_res <- reg_fun(event_date = as.Date("2020-09-01"), data = data)

# print summary
test_res$summary
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Count ~ DayNumber + Post_event + intv_trend + log(lag_count), 
#>     family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -2.9155  -0.8267  -0.1498   0.8527   4.9107  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)     3.649360   0.353805  10.315  < 2e-16 ***
#> DayNumber       0.004957   0.005517   0.899    0.369    
#> Post_event      0.714854   0.098185   7.281 3.32e-13 ***
#> intv_trend     -0.051807   0.008034  -6.448 1.13e-10 ***
#> log(lag_count)  0.050323   0.089530   0.562    0.574    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 278.729  on 41  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  95.044  on 37  degrees of freedom
#>   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
#> AIC: 350.86
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

# plot 1
test_res$plot1
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'


# plot 2
test_res$plot2
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

I don't display the plots, but you get the idea.

Now I wrap this in a function which can take a number of dates at the same time. Theoretically we could have done this in the same function.

```
reg_fun_mult <- function(event_dates, dat) {
  output <- lapply(event_dates, reg_fun, dat)
  names(output) <- event_dates # give the list elements suitable names
  return(output)
}

test_res_mult <- reg_fun_mult(eventDate, data)

# check if any variables were significant
sign <- sapply(test_res_mult, function(x) x$signif)
# look at the first ten results to see which ones have significant values
sign[1:10]
#> 2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-04 2020-01-05 2020-01-06 2020-01-07 
#>      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE 
#> 2020-01-08 2020-01-09 2020-01-10 
#>      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE


# keep only significant results
test_res_mult_sign <- test_res_mult[sign]
```

You can again look at individual summaries and plots like this:

```
# summary
test_res_mult$`2020-01-01`$summary
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Count ~ DayNumber + Post_event + intv_trend + log(lag_count), 
#>     family = "poisson", data = data_filtered)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.3085  -0.8371  -0.2015   0.9650   1.4188  
#> 
#> Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
#>                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)     4.3952688  0.9248944   4.752 2.01e-06 ***
#> DayNumber       0.0001341  0.0050776   0.026    0.979    
#> Post_event             NA         NA      NA       NA    
#> intv_trend             NA         NA      NA       NA    
#> log(lag_count) -0.1213342  0.2358350  -0.514    0.607    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 18.972  on 20  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 18.705  on 18  degrees of freedom
#>   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
#> AIC: 145.57
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

# plot 1
test_res_mult$`2020-01-01`$plot1
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'


# plot 2
test_res_mult$`2020-01-01`$plot2
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth).

#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: this is a great solution, I think it's pretty efficient and it is going to save me a lot of hassle! I will award the bounty as soon as it allows. I was wondering, is there tweak this slightly so it only includes significant ```Post_event``` results? This would be of the most interest to me, but don't stress if it is too difficult to amend.

Comment: Yes, you can run `sign <- sapply(test_res_mult, function(x) x$signif)` and then `test_res_mult[sign]` to only get the iterations with significnat results. I might have buried that part a bit since I wanted to print `sign` to show what's happening.

Comment: Great, thank you for taking the time to write this solution!

Comment: You're very welcome :) I recently wrote something very similar for my own work and was kind of sad that it was so specific it didn't make sense to share. Now I got at least to share it here :)

Comment: At least you got the chance to share it! It's nice when you come up with something for a niche problem and then get to re-use it again in some capacity.